# init not found try passing init=bootargs

Tags: 10.10, boot, ubuntu-netbook

I tried to install ubuntu in my sony CS17G notebook. After selecting the option "Install ubuntu" from the boot menu, I am always getting the error..

init not found. try passing init=bootargs.
(initramfs)

After surfing the net I came to know that sudo command will help me to fix the issue which requires a terminal. From the (inittamfs) prompt, how should I open a terminal. On using sudo command, i getting an error that 'sudo not found'.

Please help me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the installation did not complete or the disk may be damaged or the fs at least corrupt somehow.  Boot from the livecd and use the disk utility to check the health of the disk.  Run the long SMART self test and make sure the counts for pending, reallocated, and offline sectors are zero.  If that looks good, then reinstall.

Comment: Even after booting from the livecd, i face the same problem.

Comment: @Premkumar then it doesn't sound like your system is actually booting from the livecd.

Comment: How to boot from the livecd?. I have an option in the boot menu,  "run ubuntu without installation". Hope this is the option for livecd.

Comment: @Premkumar yes, and when you choose that, you also get this error?  Yet you didn't when you booted from this same cd to install the first time?

Comment: Yes when i select that option i get the same error. On selecting the option to install ubuntu also i get the same error. Is this error related to my hard drive?.

Comment: @Premkumar no, the cd must be corrupt.  Pick the check disk option.

Comment: @psusi Ubuntu mounts disks automatically in the livecd. It will not run correctly in Live mode if your damaged disk is existant on the system. I found this out the hard way when i tried to diagnose my disk... ended up buying a SATA-to-USB connectivity kit, connected my SATA drive to the Live environment after booting to the LiveCD. The LiveCD is likely not corrupt, but this issue is likely occurring.

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix ahh, good point... the livecd does try to automatically activate the swap partition if found, so if that is messed up, it could cause problems.  Unmounting the swap partition and trying again should get around that if it is the problem.

Comment: but only if you can get through... you may need to not have the disk connected first, then reconnect it later after the LiveCD is booted (not sure if that'll work but...)

Answer (score 1):

Boot using a live CD or an alternate ubuntu install (if you have multiple versions as my case). Open System -> administration -> Disk Utility and check the status of all linux partitions. Use 'Check and Repair Filsystem' for each partition ([image: see screen shot]) . The partition containing /boot files might have got corrupt. If you get an error while checking the partition, open a terminal window (Application -> accessories -> Terminal) and type

```
sudo  fsck -y /dev/xxxx
```

Replace xxxx with the device name you get from Disk Utility screen where name device written. In the example screen shot it is 'sda5'.

If 'fsck' fixes some thing, re-run it  again until it is reported clean.

Reboot without CD now and see if you are able to boot  correctly. The procedure described above fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks. Just bailed out a friend's netbook using your instructions. Spot on.